# Rails form select collection of urls only from current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My setup is `message` has many `url`.

I'm using Devise.

I'm trying to get this form select on a collection to gather only the `url`'s associated with the `current_user`. Currently it grabs all urls.

```
<%= f.select :url_id, 
  Url.order('name asc').all.collect { |u| [u.name, u.id] },
  { class: 'form-control' }
%>
```

Can I do something like change `.all` to `.where` `current_user.id`, etc...?

Comment: How's message and/or url related with the user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would share what I ended working in the end.

I added a final_url column to the `message`.

before_create combined request.base_url and short_url. Once those two were combined into a single column that helped when I could only pass two.

```
message.rb
  before_create do
    self.body = "#{self.body} #{self.url}"
  end
```

Select worked as Sebastian suggested

```
<%= f.select :url, @urls, {}, class: 'form-control' %>

message_controller.rb
@urls = Url.where('user_id = ?', current_user).pluck(:name, :final_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having your models like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :urls
end

class Url < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Then you can use `joins` from `Url` and then to up to the `User` model, and use `pluck` just to get the `url` and `id` attribute, something like:

```
def new
  @urls = Url.joins(message: :user).where('users.id = ?', current_user).pluck(:url, :id)
end
```

There you define an instance variable called `@urls` in your `new` method (I suppose it's your current scenario), which gets the urls for the `current_user`.

Note that variable is created in order to maintain the MVC logic, without adding queries in the view.

Then you can add the `select` form helper in your view, passing the `@urls` variable, an empty third argument, and then the class as a fourth one:

```
<%= f.select :url_id, @urls, {}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: I tried your scenerio. The Urls are independent objects so url doesn't have a  message_id. which causes an error. I created the column but nothing is populated in the field... I assume that is because there isn't a connection between the two models because the urls are independent of message but are connected to the user. When sending a message I want the user to decide which url to attach to it. can I run the collect scenerio in the controller with the where added?

Comment: Ok so I experimented a bit with your advice.  in the controller I have 
  @urls = Url.where('user_id = ?', current_user).pluck(:name, :short_url])
It does populate the unique url which is what I was trying to do. However it made a different issue because I was doing this in the view.
{ |u| [u.name, (request.base_url + '/' + u.short_url)] }
I'm taking the request.base_url and added the short_url to get 1 string. How can I pull that off in the controller. I thought you can only have 2 but I need 3. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: In such case you could modify the attributes after_save them or as you need, but if you want modify the attribute when you map it, something like `<%= form.select :url_id, Url.joins(message: :user).where('users.id = ?', 1).pluck(:url, :id).map{|e| ["#{request.base_url}/#{e[0]}", e[1]]} %>`